# Broker query criteria to search all multimedia components in a folder

Tags: web8, broker

I was wondering if broker query has any criteria which can work for **Location/Folder path** to search components inside a folder. I am intended to search all the binary components based inside a folder(recursively) in my DXA based application. Can anyone share if there is any out of the box criteria available which can be used to search multimedia components in a folder hierarchy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I am not sure but maybe you could try: 'PublicationMultimediaPathCriteria'? An example is found here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B2D2FF1D-8292-4A6B-9326-35F7BFD2FAA0

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and there is no such criteria to look for components in a certain folder. BUT in your case for multimedia components you should try:

```
PublicationMultimediaPathCriteria criteria = new PublicationMultimediaPathCriteria("/some/MM/path%", Criteria.LIKE);
```

Comment: Above criteria won't work as the path is same(Default to publication properties for multimedia path) for all multimedia item.

Comment: so... do you mean the folder used in CM? This data is not available once published, unless you add it to the component metadata yourself (manually or through code)